# Is it possible to handle an URL on the remote desktop (RDP connection) and redirect its opening on local machine?

Tags: remote-desktop, url, handle

1. user connects to a terminal server by RDP
2. connected to the terminal server user clicks on an url
3. this server won't open this url, but will redirect it on local machine
4. the url will be opened by local application (browser etc)

Is there any methods to achive this algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you are programmer, you can use Virtual Channel to develop 2 small add-in programs, one on the client side, one on the server side to archive that. If you prefer 3rd party, there is a free tool that's called Remote Executer for Terminal Server, it seems that it can do the trick.

Good luck

Jumeaux